# Java math.pow() returning wrong answer

Tags: java

I was using the Math.pow() method, and the results I get differ from the result I got from a calculator.

The code I used:

```
public static int getSum(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    return (int)(d*Math.pow(16.0,6.0)+c*Math.pow(16.0,4.0)+b*Math.pow(16.0,2.0)+a);
}
```

Printing

```
 getSum(0,0,128,191)
```

prints out 2147483647
while google calculator shows 3212836864.

What causes this?

Answer (score 6):

Just to add an explanation to the existing answers (if e.g. someone wonders why there is no integer overflow):

[The spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#d5e4334) says under 5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion

> In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a
>   long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int,
>   as follows:
>
> - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first    step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
> - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the    floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding
>     toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then
>     there are two cases:
>
>   - If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long,    then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>   - Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then    the result of the first step is the int value V.
> - Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
>   - The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or    negative infinity), and the result of the first step is the
>       smallest    representable value of type int or long.
>   - The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or    positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the
>       largest    representable value of type int or long.

So your `double` value returned from [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) is converted to the largest representable `int` (i.e. [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-)).

Note that this part is specific to floating-point number conversions. If your method was e.g. defined as (note the additional cast to `long`)

```
public static int getSum(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    // Casting twice doesn't make sense. It's just here for demonstration.
    return (int)(long)(d*Math.pow(16.0,6.0)+c*Math.pow(16.0,4.0)+b*Math.pow(16.0,2.0)+a);
}
```

The corresponding part in spec would be

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input
>   value.

And your method would return -1082130422 (aka integer overflow).

Answer (score 4):

Java `int` has capability of store `2^32`, which if it is signed, half is used by negative numbers. For positive numbers, can store up to `2^31 -1 = 2147483647`. You need a bigger type for this task, use `long` and it can store up to `9 223 372 036 854 775 807` when it is signed.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention, 2147483647 is a big ass prime number. It was the largest prime number known to mankind until 1867

Answer (score 3):

2,147,483,647 is the max value an int can hold.  If you need larger numbers, like in this case, make your function return a long instead.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of an integer in java is 2,147,483,647. You should keep it a double value and `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()`. You can also cast it into a long value because that is a 64 bit two's compliment integer.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to following: int --> 32 bit (2^32 -1)
Easy way to test max length is System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); ==> 2147483647

```
public static Long getSum(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return (long) (d * Math.pow(16.0, 6.0) + c * Math.pow(16.0, 4.0) + b * Math.pow(16.0, 2.0) + a);
}
```